# How should you manage internal shared libraries when using NuGet?

Tags: nuget, dependency-management

How should you manage cross-product internal changes when using NuGet? We have many teams working on individual components all of which make use of a shared library written internally. Anybody can make changes to the shared library, but changes are mandated to be backwards compatible. (Obviously this mandate is impossible if you want to make a large change like updating the .NET version of the library).

We are looking to move towards using NuGet for dependency management, but I'm not sure how this would work it a real world example. Each of our teams is operating within scrum and the assumption is that at the end of each sprint (or more frequently), each team would release updated NuGet packages for their component. This would mean that cross product dependencies are better managed. However, I don't see how this works for the core library which doesn't have any dedicated team working on it.

If I'm working on component A I want to be able to add something to the core library and immediately make use of it. Currently the core library is project referenced in all of the components Visual Studio solutions. Would the correct approach be to create a pre-release package on each commit and to update the component to use this? If so, when should a stable version of the core library be created?

Comment: Are you using Visual Studio? Were you aware that you can create Nuget Package Sources using folders? At my current company, we use a network folder (from a build machine) and place nuget packages for internal use there. Tools -> Nuget Package Manager -> Nuget Manager Settings -> Package Sources -> Add package source